# Using Predis, how to SET (i.e. store) a multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I am [following this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-redis-in-php) to get started with Predis in PHP. In this guide, they have given the **`set()`** function to store key value pairs:

> ```
> //sets message to contain "Hello world"
> $redis->set(';message';, ';Hello world';);
> ```

Now the data I want to cache using predis is a multidimensional associative array coming from a MongoDB database, and it looks like

```
allRowsDataArray = array(
  row0 = array(
    key0 = value0,
    key1 = value1,
    ...so on
  ),
  row1 = array(
    field0 = value0,
    field1 = value1,
    ...so on
  ),
  ...so on
)
```

So in order to save this array in cache, when I do

```
$redis->set('allRowsDataArray', $allRowsDataArray);
```

I get this exception/error:

```
Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php on line 390
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php on line 391
Fatal error: Uncaught Predis\Response\ServerException: ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length in /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Client.php:370 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Client.php(335): Predis\Client->onErrorResponse(Object(Predis\Command\StringSet), Object(Predis\Response\Error)) #1 /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Client.php(314): Predis\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\StringSet)) #2 /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/index.php(110): Predis\Client->__call('set', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/testProject/plugins/predis/predis/src/Client.php on line 370
```

So the question is that what am I missing? How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: [set](https://redis.io/commands/set) needs a string value, you can use [`serialize($allRowsDataArray)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and then `unserialize` it when retrieving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Set` method expect value to be string. Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to save data.

```
$redis->set('allRowsDataArray', json_encode($allRowsDataArray));
```

And use `json_decode()` to retrieve from `Redis`.